# Serviço web que gera imagem de gráfico

Tags: api, gráfico, services

Preciso encontrar uma solução para gerar imagens de gráficos pela URL. O Google oferece uma API, mas será aposentada logo.

Alguém conhece algum serviço como o do Google?

O objetivo é enviar gráficos no corpo do email.

Comment: Um problema disso é toda hora que um serviço fecha, você perde tudo que foi enviado. O ideal seria gerar você mesmo as imagens numa aplicação própria, assim teria controle total sobre a mesma (além de poder monitorar o que foi visto por quem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei um serviço que pode ser útil:
http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?GXchart30,

O problema é o que o Bacco disse: Se o serviço fechar, já era.

O ideal é ter um script do lado do servidor que gere os gráficos que você quer. O componente OWC é uma saída mas gera uns gráficos bem feios.